# Flutter does popping a screen with a firestore stream reread the document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new on flutter and firebase, i am currently developing app which have a streambuilder with stream from a firestore snapshot, the statefulwidget class is more or less like this :

```
StreamBuilder(
 stream: ItemService().getItemsWithStatus([1]),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Item>> snapshot) {
     //Widget to show information
                                 
     }
  )
```

and i get the stream from itemService class like this

```
class ItemService{
Stream<List<Item>> getItemsWithStatus(List<int> status) {
    return _firestore
        .collection(itemsPath)
        .where('status', whereIn: status)
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((DocumentSnapshot document) => Item.fromDb(document.data()))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

the question is , when i close the screen with that streambuilder and then reopen it would it read the data again from firestore (and doubling my read count)? if yes then how can i possibly do to avoid reread?

Thankyou, any advice will really be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Probably no. You can check with this alteration:

```
(DocumentSnapshot document) {
  print(document.metadata.isFromCache);
  Item.fromDb(document.data());
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering i already tried it and it says that it from cache but the weird thing, suppose i have 7 item on the list, and i only edit 1 item, isnt it supposed to get 6 from cache and 1 from firestore? cause when i print it says all of them from firestore not from cache. is it supposed to be like this? thankyou